# where should this check logic go?

Tags: c#

I have a function that draw an image on graphics:

```
private void DrawSmallImage(Graphics g)
{
            if (this.SmallImage == null) return; 

            var smallPicHeight = this.Height / 5;

            var x = this.ClientSize.Width - smallPicHeight;
            var y = this.ClientSize.Height - smallPicHeight;

            g.DrawImage(this.SmallImage, x, y, smallPicHeight, smallPicHeight);
 }
```

the check  `if (this.SmallImage == null) return;`  should be in the function DrawSmallImage or should be in the caller? which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to put the check logic would be in the calling method.

It is generally considered best to design a method for a single, specific purpose. Not only does this keep your design cleaner, it will decrease the coupling on the method and make it reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in the caller. The method DrawSmallImage shouldn't know anything about the state of the class. It's purpose is to DrawSmallImage.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the check there, and pass `SmallImage` as a parameter to the `DrawSmallImage` method.

This way it can be reused for any image.

Something like

```
private void DrawSmallImage(Graphics g, Image smallImage) 
{ 
            if (smallImage == null) return;  

            var smallPicHeight = this.Height / 5; 

            var x = this.ClientSize.Width - smallPicHeight; 
            var y = this.ClientSize.Height - smallPicHeight; 

            g.DrawImage(smallImage, x, y, smallPicHeight, smallPicHeight); 
 }
```

Comment: Why would you pass a null image to a function to draw an image? How does this help determine whether or not the image should be drawn small?

Comment: Never said you SHOULD pass a null, but I said that your method should check that it IS NOT NULL. And passing smallImage as a param, will allow you to reuse this method with other images. You might even want to pass the height factor as a param if you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to throw an Exception when this happens:

```
if (this.SmallImage == null) 
    throw new NullReferenceException("Small image can't be null");
```

Then expect the caller to check a property like:

```
bool HasSmallImage
{
    get { return this.SmallImage!=null; }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to throw this exception explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

SmallImage is a member field.  The best design, in my view, is the one that prevents it from ever being null (e.g. have it initialized in every constructor, and throw an ArgumentException if it's about to be set to null).  Of course, you haven't given much background, so this may not be possible.  But it's definitely something to consider.

Either way, you can definitely specify that it must be non-null when this method is called.  This is a type of pre-condition.

Comment: the SmallImage is coming from outside, it is possible to be null.

Comment: Is it a public field, or are you requiring a setter/set property?  If the latter, you can throw an exception if someone tries to set it to null.